# Discrepancy in PCA results between Python's 'sklearn' and R's 'prcomp'

Tags: python, r, data-analysis

I am trying to get the explained variance from PCA results using both Python's sklearn and R's prcomp. However, the results I'm getting are different.

Using Python's sklearn, I have the following code:

```
X = China_dc[days].values
print(X)

# PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=3)

pca.fit(X)
# transform data
X_reduced = pca.transform(X)
X_reduced.shape

exp_var = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
cumul_var = np.cumsum(exp_var)
exp_var_ratio = pca.explained_variance_ratio_

print('Explained variances: ',exp_var)
print('Cumulative variances: ',cumul_var)
print('Ratio explained variances: ', exp_var_ratio)
```

This gives me:

```
Explained variances:  [9.99161637e-01 5.16487694e-04 1.18391188e-04]
Cumulative variances:  [0.99916164 0.99967812 0.99979652]
Ratio explained variances:  [9.99161637e-01 5.16487694e-04 1.18391188e-04]
```

For the R equivalent, I'm using:

```
X <- as.matrix(China_dc[, days])
print(X)

# Compute PCA
pca_result <- prcomp(X, scale. = TRUE, center = TRUE)

# Number of principal components to keep
num_components <- 3

# Extract the scores for the principal components
X_reduced <- pca_result$x[, 1:num_components]
print(dim(X_reduced))

exp_var <- pca$sdev^2 / sum(pca$sdev^2)
cumul_var <- cumsum(exp_var)
exp_var_ratio <- pca$sdev^2 / sum(pca$sdev^2)

# Print the results
cat("Explained variances: ", formatC(exp_var, format="e", digits=9), "\n")
cat("Cumulative variances: ", formatC(cumul_var, format="f", digits=9), "\n")
cat("Ratio explained variances: ", formatC(exp_var, format="e", digits=9), "\n")
```

The results are:

```
Explained variances:  4.643525829e+01 1.761293944e+01 2.850233794e+00 1.459302013e+00 1.292069560e+00 7.388019414e-01 5.725802159e-01 2.614469579e-01 1.718798945e-01 1.342837656e-01 9.996045343e-02 8.345580176e-02 7.084763008e-02 5.173522936e-02 3.444298029e-02 3.145182460e-02 2.805027601e-02 1.591606495e-02 1.157167108e-02 1.150884734e-02 8.895829763e-03 7.434083343e-03 6.268889184e-03 3.525675290e-03 3.028483997e-03 1.322221936e-03 7.930392547e-04 4.946154929e-04 2.815427441e-04 1.196541370e-04 7.545291900e-05 2.387045794e-05 1.879698812e-31 
Cumulative variances:  46.435258285 64.048197721 66.898431515 68.357733527 69.649803087 70.388605029 70.961185245 71.222632202 71.394512097 71.528795863 71.628756316 71.712212118 71.783059748 71.834794977 71.869237958 71.900689782 71.928740058 71.944656123 71.956227794 71.967736641 71.976632471 71.984066555 71.990335444 71.993861119 71.996889603 71.998211825 71.999004864 71.999499480 71.999781022 71.999900677 71.999976130 72.000000000 72.000000000 
Ratio explained variances:  4.643525829e+01 1.761293944e+01 2.850233794e+00 1.459302013e+00 1.292069560e+00 7.388019414e-01 5.725802159e-01 2.614469579e-01 1.718798945e-01 1.342837656e-01 9.996045343e-02 8.345580176e-02 7.084763008e-02 5.173522936e-02 3.444298029e-02 3.145182460e-02 2.805027601e-02 1.591606495e-02 1.157167108e-02 1.150884734e-02 8.895829763e-03 7.434083343e-03 6.268889184e-03 3.525675290e-03 3.028483997e-03 1.322221936e-03 7.930392547e-04 4.946154929e-04 2.815427441e-04 1.196541370e-04 7.545291900e-05 2.387045794e-05 1.879698812e-31
```

Why am I getting different results between the two methods? Are there any inherent differences between sklearn PCA and R's prcomp? Or is there an issue in my implementation?

Comment: are you scaling the data in python? I see the R code has `scale` and `center` as TRUE.

Comment: Also according sklearn PCA [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), if you you're data is really it might use a randomized state solver, though it shouldn't cause a massive difference between the results

Answer (score 1):

The [sklearn PCA documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) says

> The input data is centered but not scaled for each feature before applying the SVD.

so if you want to match this behaviour in R you should use `center=TRUE, scale = FALSE` in your `prcomp()` call.

[This discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/22104) points out that if you want to do scaling in sklearn you can do it via a pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), PCA())
pca.fit_transform(X)
```